# How to check if the current event is the last event in the series of events sent to webhook?

Tags: javascript, api, web-applications, google-app-engine

I am coding a google apps script web app to react events from telegram API with a chat bot. I've already set webhook to google webhook to collect events, so I can't use `logger.log` to get the log. Therefore, I use the `sendMessage` method of the telegram API to get log of events. I use `doPost` to send HTTP requests to the telegram API whenever an event comes.

I aim to make chat bot resend a group of photos (as an album form) uploaded to the chat group but I am stuck at the `sendMediaGroup` method of the telegram API. This method requires 2 parameters: `chat_id` and `media`, where `media` is an Array of `InputMediaAudio`, `InputMediaDocument, InputMediaPhoto` and `InputMediaVideo`.

In my case, `media` is an array of `InputMediaPhoto`. The problem is when an album of photos is sent to the chat group, the telegram API responds with a number of events (each one contains the same `media_group_id` and each of photo's property) equal to number of photos in the album instead of an event that contains a media group composing all photos. Therefore I must collect the `InputMediaPhoto` from each event then push them to `media` one by one. But I don't know how to help the bot identify the final event to stop pushing them and do `sendMediaGroup`. The shape of my code is below:

```
// Declare bot token, set webhook, declare myID as bot ID 
// Declare functions such as sendMessage sendMediaGroup etc
// main body runs doPost to response events

var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();

var msgIDstring = cache.get("msgID");

var mediastring = cache.get("mymedia");
if (mediastring == null){
  var media = []
}
else{
  var media = JSON.parse(mediastring);
}

function doPost(e) {
 
  let update = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
  let chat_id = update.message.chat.id; // group chat id

  sendMessage(myID, JSON.stringify(update), 'HTML');

if (update.message.media_group_id == null) {

// do other methods

}

  else {
    
    if (msgIDstring == null){
      cache.put("msgID",String(update.message.message_id));
      let photo_id = String(update.message.photo[0].file_id);
      let InputMediaPhoto = {
      'type': "photo",
      'media': photo_id
    }
    
    media.push(InputMediaPhoto);
    cache.put("mymedia",JSON.stringify(media));
    }   
    
    else {
      let i = update.message.message_id - Number(msgIDstring);
       
      while (i==1) {
        
        let photo_id = String(update.message.photo[0].file_id);
        let InputMediaPhoto = {
        'type': "photo",
        'media': photo_id
        };    
        media.push(InputMediaPhoto); 
        sendMessage(myID, JSON.stringify(media), 'HTML');       
        cache.put("mymedia",JSON.stringify(media));        
        cache.put("msgID",String(update.message.message_id));

        if (i==0){
          break;
        }
      }
             
      sendMessage(myID, String(i), 'HTML'); // **It's stop here with "0" sent to the chat bot**
      sendMessage(myID, cache.get("mymedia"), 'HTML');
      sendMediaGroup(chat_id,media);   
                      
    }
    
  }  
  //sendMessage(myID, JSON.stringify(media), 'HTML');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the current event is the last event in the series of events sent to a webhook, it may depend on the specific details and context of your webhook implementation. However, in general, you can include a parameter in your webhook payload that indicates the total number of events or the index of the current event in the series.

For example, let's say you are sending a series of events with a total count of 10. You can include a parameter "event_count" in each event payload that indicates the total count, and another parameter "event_index" that indicates the index of the current event in the series, starting from 0. Then, in your webhook receiving endpoint, you can check if the value of "event_index" is 9 (which is the last index in a zero-based counting system for a series of 10 events).

Alternatively, you might implement some kind of flagging mechanism, where the last event in the series includes a specific flag in the payload indicating that it is the last event. Then, in your webhook receiving endpoint, you can check if the flag is present in the current event payload to determine if it is the last event.

Again, the specific implementation may vary depending on your use case and the details of your webhook framework.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).